# Trying to access a <c:set variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have this line in the header of my JSP `<script>var logicalName = "${logicalName}"</script>` which is resolving to the correct value.

I want to access this value via javascript/jquery. How do I do this?

This is not working `console.log($logicalName);`

Comment: `console.log(logicalName)`...

Comment: You're creating a global variable called `logicalName`, not `$logicalName`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Let me give this a try.

Comment: console.log(logicalName) worked. That was easy. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, would someone mind explaining to me why this was downvoted so that I can learn to ask better questions?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted the question. Still, your problem was that you weren't using EL in your last statement: `${logicalName}` is parsed by EL, while `$logicalName` is a javascript variable that hasn't been declared anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the string symbol from your parameter

```
console.log(logicalName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log("${logicalName}");
```

and

```
console.log(logicalName);
```

Both will work!

Comment: The string `${logicalName}` is replaced by EL at the server, whereas `logicalName` is a reference to a plain JavaScript variable which is replaced during runtime.